# How to subset an R data.table from inside a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge data.table and I want to create a function which among others, subsets the `DT`, say keep the rows with `col.a` more than 4.
I have consulted the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) and help files but I don't seem to come up with a solution.

```
set.seed(1)

DT <- data.table(col.a = 1:5, col.b = rev(11:15), col.c = rnorm(5))

remove.low.alphas.and.create.col.d <- function(my.datatable){
  my.datatable[, col.d := col.b + col.c]
  subset(my.datatable, col.a >= 4)
#   my.datatable[col.a >= 4]  # and other failed attempts...
#   my.datatable <- my.datatable[col.a >= 4]
#   my.datatable <- subset(my.datatable, col.a >= 4)
#   my.datatable
#   setDT(my.datatable)[col.a >= 4]
}

DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c
# 1:     1    15 -0.6264538
# 2:     2    14  0.1836433
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286
# 4:     4    12  1.5952808
# 5:     5    11  0.3295078
```

After running

```
remove.low.alphas.and.create.col.d(my.datatable = DT)
#    col.a col.b     col.c    col.d
# 1:     4    12 1.5952808 13.59528
# 2:     5    11 0.3295078 11.32951
```

`DT` remains unchanged.

```
DT
#    col.a col.b      col.c    col.d
# 1:     1    15 -0.6264538 14.37355
# 2:     2    14  0.1836433 14.18364
# 3:     3    13 -0.8356286 12.16437
# 4:     4    12  1.5952808 13.59528
# 5:     5    11  0.3295078 11.32951
```

I could use `DT <- remove.low.alphas.and.create.col.d(my.datatable = DT)` but I do not want to. I want everything to happen inside the function.

Comment: You could use `assign`, e.g. `f <- function(my.datatable){tmp <- as.character(substitute(my.datatable));my.datatable[, col.d := col.b + col.c];my.datatable <- subset(my.datatable, col.a >= 4);assign(tmp, value = my.datatable, envir = parent.frame())}`. However, I dunno if this is the best data.table way to go here...

Comment: Are you asking for *delete rows by reference*? `DT` was changed inside the function, additional column was added by reference. I would avoid the trick mentioned by @lukeA as it doesn't have any advantage over `DT <- fun(...)`. You cannot delete rows by reference (yet) so I would stick with `DT <- fun(...)` way.

Comment: So if I want to avoid `assign()` I can use something like `my.datatable <- my.datatable[col.a >= 4]` outside a function, but not inside a function... Unless it is the last command in a function, so as to assign what the function returns to the original DT, and then continue the rest of my script writing another function... I must be missing something... I will check how things go with `assign()`....